# Write a batch script MAC OS X

Tags: macos, batch-file

I have this code in a .bat file for Windows

```
@echo off
echo To do something..
pause
del fileName /Q
```

Actually it prints out something and after that it waits until user press any key. After the user presses a key, it deletes a specified file.
I need the same but for Mac OS. First I need to know how to @echo off? Which I could not achieve.
Pause I can do with:

```
read -n 1 -p Press
```

Comment: `rm -i fileName` will ask if you want to delete a file

Comment: Go read about bash, it's the closest equivalent of window's `.bat`

Comment: Thanks Mark! It's near what I'm looking for, but in this case user will know that something is deleting which unwanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo To do something..
read -n 1 -p Press
rm -f fileName > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```